# Is FreeBSD license easier than Ubuntu/Fedora/CentOS/ArchLinux when it comes to GPL + Close source + Sell?

Tags: linux, debian, freebsd, opensolaris, licenses

If I use FreeBSD/OpenSolaris, and stop using Ubuntu/Fedora/CentOS/ArchLinux, migrate my all applications to FreeBSD/OpenSolaris will that reduce license problems?

Specially, GPL/LGPL is very complicated combination, and specially it turns out to be that Linux distro licenses are very complicated then Unix licenses? (please correct me if i am wrong)

Seems like FreeBSD allows to sell and also allowes to make closed source where Linux GPL license is most confusing when it comes to sell the product for derived works.

I was reading this article which, scares me that those guy can reject anyone just with a single tiny word mistake: http://projects.opensource.org/pipermail/license-discuss/2011-December/000039.html

Comment: Are you running systems on FreeBSD/Ubuntu/…? Or are you distributing FreeBSD/Ubuntu/…? What license problems are you referring to? Note that not all of FreeBSD/Ubuntu/… is under the same license. Also, the GPL does allow selling, what it doesn't allow is restricting the recipient from making and distributing copies. Finally, several of your sentences look like they're cut halfway, so it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  As long as you use software produced by others, you will need to understand the licenses it is provided to you under.  BSD, GPL & other licenses have different requirements, especially to those who want to redistribute the software covered by them, and switching from one to another just means you need to learn how to work with a different set of requirements.

As for the article you reference, their point is that a tiny mistake in the wording of a license can make a huge legal difference, which is why licenses need to be drafted by people who understand the legal issues involved.   Their rejection though only covers whether the license will be listed by the Open Source Initiative as a certified Open Source license.

Comment: Also consider David Wheelers essay on licenses.:http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html. Very short version: Use one of the mainstream licenses (GPL, BSD), anything else _will_ become a hindrance somewhere soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

The alanc's answer is correct, but please also read this links before of judge the GPL license:

- [Frequently Asked Questions about the GNU Licenses](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html)
- [Selling Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html)